# Custom RMSE not the same as taking the root of built-in Keras MSE for same prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have defined a custom RMSE function:

```
def rmse(y_pred, y_true):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))
```

I was evaluating it against the mean squared error provided by Keras:

`keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)`

The values I get for MSE and RMSE metrics respectively for some (the same) prediction are:

`mse: 115.7218 - rmse: 8.0966`

Now, when I take the root of the MSE, I get `10.7574`, which is obviously higher than the RMSE the custom RMSE function outputs. I haven't been able to figure out why this is so, nor have I found any related posts on this particular topic. Is there maybe a mistake in the RMSE function that I'm simply not seeing? Or is it somehow related to how Keras defines `axis=-1` in the MSE function (purpose of which I haven't fully understood yet)?

Here is where I invoke the RMSE and MSE:

`model.compile(loss="mae", optimizer="adam", metrics=["mse", rmse])`

So I would expect the root of MSE to be the same as the RMSE.

I originally asked this question on Cross Validated but it was put on hold as off-topic.

Comment: where is your result `mse: 115.7218 - rmse: 8.0966` came from? model.evaluate or model.fit or what? Please provide as much information as you can

Comment: They're validation results from model.fit after an epoch has finished. Here are results from model.evaluate for some prediction: `mse 60.0054 - rmse 6.8625`. The root of the MSE is `7.7463`.

Comment: question, why should it be the same?

Comment: How did you do this comparison? Maybe posting that code will help to figure out the problem.

Comment: @mka could you solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there maybe a mistake in the RMSE loss function that I'm simply not
>   seeing? Or is it somehow related to how Keras defines axis=-1 in the
>   MSE loss function (purpose of which I haven't fully understood yet)?

When Keras does the loss calculation, the batch dimension is retained which is the reason for `axis=-1`. The returned value is a tensor. This is because the loss for each sample **may** have to be weighted before taking the mean depending on whether certain arguments are passed in the `fit()` method like `sample_weight`.

I get the same results with both the approaches.

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K

def rmse(y_pred, y_true):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))

l1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(32))
l2 = keras.layers.Dense(10)(l1)
model = keras.Model(inputs=l1, outputs=l2)

train_examples = np.random.randn(5,32)
train_labels=np.random.randn(5,10)
```

**MSE approach**

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.evaluate(train_examples, train_labels)
```

**RMSE approach**

```
model.compile(loss=rmse, optimizer='adam')
model.evaluate(train_examples, train_labels)
```

**Output**

```
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/sample - loss: 1.9011
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/sample - loss: 1.3788
```

sqrt(1.9011) = 1.3788

Answer (score 0):

Although `sqrt(mse)` is equal to `rmse` for a simple model configuration as Manoj's answer has shown, I faced this problem for a complex model configuration and was unable to figure out why it happened. However, I have found a workaround to get rid of that if someone badly needs to monitor `rmse` as a metric but facing the same problem in the question. I used the `LambdaCallback` in the `callbacks` to print the `rmse` of training and validation after every epoch and it worked:

```
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred)))

rmse_print_callback = keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch,logs: 
                 print(f"rmse: {rmse(training_labels, model.predict(training_data)):.4f} - val_rmse: {rmse(validation_labels, model.predict(validation_data)):.4f}"))

model.fit(training_data, training_labels, epochs= 100, callbacks=[rmse_print_callback])
```